# Mips32: Creating Sparse Array Error

Tags: arrays, mips, sparse-matrix, mips32

I am trying to create a sparse array from a regular array but I have one problem.
First here is a part of the code:

```
    la $t1,arrayA

loopSparseA:

    beq $t0,10,endloopSparseA
    add $t0,$t0,1   
    beqz $t1,loopSparseA
    addi $t1,$t1,4
    j loopSparseA
```

Array A has 10 values of 0.
Note that this is only a part and the whole loop is working fine allready.
The problem is on this line:

```
beqz $t1,loopSparseA
```

This jump should happen 10 times, instead it never happens.
Any tips?

Comment: _"`beqz $t1,loopSparseA` This jump sould happen 10 times"_ Why would a jump that requires `$t1` to equal zero happen when you initialized `$t1` to the address of `arrayA` right before the loop?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your comment.Let me post something more to help eachother.This is array A:

    arrayA: .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

This is the initalization:

     la $t1,arrayA

This is the step:

    addi $t1,$t1,4

Shouldn't it check if every shell of arrayA is equal to zero, one at a time?

Comment: `$t1` is loaded with the address `arrayA` and is only incremented in your code, so `$t1` can never be zero, so the branch never happens.